# Installing TinyMCE Text Editor

Tags: 7, forms, wysiwyg

I followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hq5NwrIUVrg) in youtube for installing TinyMCE Editor in drupal. Below are the steps I did.

```
1. Downloaded and installed the updated WYSIWYG 7.x-2.2, IMCE 7.x-1.9 and IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge 7.x-1.0 succesfully.

2. Downloaded TinyMCE and placed it on `htdocs\drupal\sites\all\libraries` succesfully.

3. Installed TinyMCE unsuccesfully.
```

I refresh drupal's page and still gets the 'Not installed.' message.

[image]

I suspect the path may be wrong/different from the image above. The actual path in my computer is `sites\all\libraries\tinymce\js\tinymce\tinymce.min.js`

I downloaded TinyMCE [here](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi @Aliyah, which version of the TinyMCE  you are using like 4.x or 3.x?

Comment: @PankajSachdeva TinyMCE 4.2.7 :)

Comment: please use the version 3.5.x to work properly. I hope it will work.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the folder names to match the correct path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be TinyMCE version issue with 4.7.x. Once I have facing the same problem. Then I uses the version 3.5.x of TinyMCE and its worked fine for me.

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do quite a bit of work to get WYSIWYG to work properly. While I preferred TinyMCE, I ended up using CKeditor 4.4.4 after it was all said and done, since I am using "Footnotes" Add-on. The setting for this editor were much easier to configure and get working.

Good documentation on this is easy to find and troubleshoot: http://ckeditor.com/

I ended up adding the editor the Libraries folder and changed settings in the modules folder to point to the file directory that was needed. It's been over a year since I did this and I changed things so many times that I can't remember what was right or wrong.

The end result is, it's nice having a WYSIWYG that works, that I haven't had to mess with for over a year.